# Is there a way to pass arbitrary precision numbers between fortran and python?

Tags: python, c, fortran, arbitrary-precision

I am currently writing a program that is heavy on finite differencing. The problem is that to get the accuracy I'd need, I need to use arbitrary precision arithmetic. I have a purely Python script that does the job, but it's rather slow so I'm thinking of passing the task of calculating the finite differences to a compiled Fortran code.

The current implementation I'm working on is that I use SymPy and mpmath to generate multiple precision initial data in Python, save it on some text file that then gets read by F2PY'd Fortran code, who then does most of the work in arbitrary precision. Fortran saves the data in some other file, and Python reads it for some post-processing.

It would be useful to me if I can just freely pass arbitrary precision numbers between Fortran and Python (say, for example, mpath's mpf data type and mpfun's mp_real), instead of going through the trouble of reading and writing multiple precision data. If this is possible with other languages instead, like C, I'd be interested to know also. Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Instead of passing the arbitrary-precision values between Python and Fortran via text files, you might be able to pass them using string arguments, reading/writing to the strings within your code.

Comment: As the comment from M.S.B. suggests if you are using mp_fun this boils down to how you can pass variables of type mp_real between python and Fortran. You can either do this directly, or indirectly by converting to a type which you know how to pass, passing that, and then converting back. How you might do this I have no idea - I don't know python.

Comment: gmpy2 may also be useful? https://mpmath.org/doc/current/setup.html#using-gmpy-optional

Answer (score 0):

Look at cython.  You can compile with gfortran and gcc, import with an equivalent C header and from there either use cython or the python C api to do just about anything.  You can splice fortran into C pretty easily and C into python.  There's a very good guide available at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html as well as many questions and answers on the stack about specific items.

Comment: That tutorial is extremely obsolete. By extremely I mean by several decades. Fortran 2003 brought modern ways for interoperability with C, see [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].